# How can I access the inherited static property from the inherited static method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a super class Foo with a static method and an instance method which both console.log() a static property.

How can I get the static method to property reference the correct static property. As you can see here it is only referencing the super class property and not the sub class property.

```
class Foo{
    whoAmI(){
        console.log(this.constructor.someStaticVar)
    }
    static whoAmI_static(){
        console.log(Foo.someStaticVar) // is there a way to call the calling class and not the superclass here?
    }
}
Foo.someStaticVar = 'I am Foo'


class Bar extends Foo{

}
Bar.someStaticVar = 'I am Bar'



let barInstance = new Bar()
Bar.whoAmI_static()
barInstance.whoAmI()
```

Expected output:

```
I am Bar
I am Bar
```

Actual Output:

```
I am Foo
I am Bar
```

Comment: Why do the methods have the same name? Are you trying to call a static method from outside the class?

Comment: @adeneo I changed the name for clarity which does not effect the code.

Comment: Well, the `whoAmI_static` function still logs `Foo.someStaticVar`, and it always will. Unless you also change `Foo.someStaticVar` it's not going to produce any other result ?

Comment: You could just replace `Foo` with `this` instead, and get the result you want

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gze6r2z9/2/